# Githooks with two remote servers

Tags: git, githooks

Is it possible to make a githook (or something else) to connect two remote servers?

Here is how it looks now:

1. I'm working on a local copy of git repository that is on `vps#1`.
2. We have `vps#2` which contains a webpage.

what I want is a solution which gives me an option to update the git repository to webserver when I want.

I am wondering if making another "local copy" on remote server is good idea?

Any sugestions?

Comment: Can you provide some more details. Right now, it is very vague and confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to add the webserver as a remote and do a push when you need to update it.

```
$ git remote add webserver <path to repo on webserver>
$ git push webserver master
```

Comment: that is good for now, Thanks ! now i think about make pull on remote from local xd